# ASP.Net login via Azure SSO error when browsing "This site can't be reached"

Tags: asp.net, azure, single-sign-on

I am new to integrating Azure SSO to an ASP.Net web application so I followed these steps
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp and was able to run it in my local machine. However when I tried uploading it in one of our test server and browse it I encountered this error "This site can't be reached". I checked the application pool and it automatically stops meaning it's been trying a couple of times to access and fails. I am just wondering if I missed any steps in configuring my application in Azure like recognizing my test server so they can communicate or something, not really sure?. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Consider that we don't have access to your project: when you post, we have no way to tell if you "missed any steps", unless you list the steps you took. See [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved in yesterday. I double checked the Project > Properties > Web > Start URL and replaced it with the production server URL. :D